# Django Generic List/Detail Class based views

Tags: python, django

I have a Generic ListView, each item in my html list links to a DetailView.

Now I'd like to increment the MyModel(DetailView) object "views"-field (integerfield) on each click.

All I seem to have at hand in the DetailView is get_context_data? So how do I update my model on this action?

n.b. Thinking out loud, should this be middleware functionality?

**edit**
Ok it seems I do have get_object and get_queryset available but those are empty (print kwargs).. also updating the integer field in context data (which seems ugly and unwanted) runs 3 times on one click (3, 6, 9 etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed do it in get_object method, like this:

```
class YourView(DetailView):

    queryset = YourModel.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        object = super(YourView, self).get_object()
        object.views = object.views + 1
        object.save()
        return object
```

Comment: Well I guess the model is not a singleton, so this could work, but I'm still wondering if middleware is better :)

Comment: Middleware will work for all requests, not only to this view, it's a certain overhead.

Comment: Is there a logical reason why any print statement I put within the detailview is printed 3 times on a click to that particular url?

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe get_context_data method is used somewhere else. Maybe you can provide some code?

Comment: It was caused by the django dev server, which was missing a favicon link, somehow this causes the server to parse the request again..